# How to handle multiple activities interacting with each other?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an application with 4 or 5 activities! Let's say A, B, C, D and E.

It is more or less possible to jump from every activity to every other activity!

Lets say a user goes A -> B -> E -> D.

Now he wants to open B (again). I now want my application to recognise, that there already is one active B somewhere in the activity stack and reactivate it (or at least finish the old B and create a new one).

I dont want to finish all activities when creating new ones, because it is likely that the user often uses the backbutton.

possible solutions would be: create a activity stack yourself and process it in bundles or to use some static structures.

But there has to be a much simpler/nicer way, is there??

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Isn't [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) what you need?

Comment: @a.ch. He wants the exact opposite.  CLEAR_TOP changes A -> B -> E -> D -> B to A -> B (it clears the top of the stack).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `singleInstance` value or `singleTask` value in launch mode tag in your manifest.

`android:launchMode=["multiple" | "singleTop" |"singleTask" | "singleInstance"]`

[According to android developers fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element)

The `singleTask` and `singleInstance` modes also differ from each other only in one respect:

A `singleTask` activity allows other activities to be part of its task. It's always at the root of its task, but other activities (necessarily `standard` and `singleTop` activities) can be launched into that task.

A `singleInstance` activity, on the other hand, permits no other activities to be part of its task. It's the only activity in the task. If it starts another activity, that activity is assigned to a different task — as if `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` was in the intent.

Comment: hey VidaLux! that seems to be the solution! i'll check on that next week! thanks a lot